# Crop variants for tt_content image

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I tried the first time the new image manipulation feature in TYPO3 and stumbled upon some problems. I am using TYPO3 8.7.16. The image processing is working correctly (tested in install tool using ImageMagick).

For testing purposes I overrided the TCA of tt_content:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['image']['config'] ['overrideChildTca']['columns']['crop'] = [
    'config' => [
        'cropVariants' => [
            'desktop' => [
                'title' => 'Desktop',
                'selectedRatio' => '4:3',
                'allowedAspectRatios' => [
                    '4:3' => [
                        'title' => '4:3',
                        'value' => 4 / 3,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'tablet' => [
                'title' => 'Tablet',
                'selectedRatio' => '16:9',
                'allowedAspectRatios' => [
                    '16:9' => [
                        'title' => '16:9',
                        'value' => 16 / 9,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'mobile' => [
                'title' => 'Mobile',
                'selectedRatio' => '2:3',
                'allowedAspectRatios' => [
                    '16:9' => [
                        'title' => '2:3',
                        'value' => 2 / 3,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

When I use the editor for image manipulation I can crop the different formats and after accepting the manipulation I see the cropped images as preview in the content element:

[image: After manipulating the images]

After saving the content element I see the following (the cropped images are not shown anymore):

[image: After saving the content element]

Is this a bug? But that doesn't bother me much for now.

Now I tried to show e.g. the cropped desktop image in frontend. I copied the Media/Rendering/Image.html partial and changed the content to:

```
<f:image image="{file}" cropVariant="desktop" width="480" alt="{file.alternative}" title="{file.title}" />
```

I thought that is enough to show the cropped image, but it was not. I see the original file. When I debugged the file reference I see, that the configuration for the cropped images are stored correctly in sys_file_reference:

[image: debugging information]

Now I have no clue what to do to get the cropped images in frontend.

Any ideas?

Edit: Now I found the problem, I had some issues with ImageMagick, so that the cropped images cannot be created.

Answer (score 1):

i would recommend you to look at the article from Clickstorm
[Clickstorm CropVariant Images](https://www.clickstorm.de/blog/crop-funktion-fuer-bilder-in-typo3-8-7/)

You can easily access the cropVariants with srcset.

```html
<f:if condition="{files}">
  <f:image src="{image.id}" treadIdAsReference="1" srcset="{f:uri.image(image:image.id,width:'2500',height:'816',cropVariant:'desktop')}" alt="{files.0.alternative}" />
</f:if>
```

Maybe you use the Picture Element like this:

```html
<picture>
 <source media="(min-width: 1400px)" srcset="{f:uri.image(src:'{image.uid}',treatIdAsReference:'1',width:'1400',cropVariant:'default')}">
 <source media="(max-width: 1399px) and (min-width:1025px)" srcset="{f:uri.image(src:'{image.uid}',treatIdAsReference:'1',cropVariant:'default-md')}">
 <source media="(max-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait)" srcset="{f:uri.image(src:'{image.uid}',treatIdAsReference:'1',width:'768',cropVariant:'tablet-portrait')}">
 <source media="(max-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape)" srcset="{f:uri.image(src:'{image.uid}',treatIdAsReference:'1',width:'768',cropVariant:'tablet-landscape')}">
 <source media="(max-width: 667px) and (orientation:portrait)" srcset="{f:uri.image(src:'{image.uid}',treatIdAsReference:'1',width:'667',cropVariant:'smartphone-portrait')}">
 <source media="(max-width: 667px) and (orientation:landscape)" srcset="{f:uri.image(src:'{image.uid}',treatIdAsReference:'1',width:'667',cropVariant:'smartphone-landscape')}">
 <img src="{f:uri.image(crop: image.crop, src: image.id, cropVariant:'default')}"title="{image.title}" alt="{image.alternative}" />
</picture>
```

I hope that help you in getting started for the Frontend part.